# How can I sort the array of class?

Tags: c++

I have made the class having 2d array (4 x 4) and maximum value in 2d array like below:

```
class B {
public:
    int shape[4][4] = { 0 };
    int maxh = 0;

    B() {};

    void record(int module[4][4]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                shape[i][j] = module[i][j];
                if (shape[i][j] > maxh) { maxh = shape[i][j]; }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

If there is a class 'B' array,

```
B b_arr = new B[30000];
```

how do I sort the class object array by the maximum value?

I have tried to sort array like below code, but I have a stack overflow error.

```
int partition(B arr[], int p, int r) {
    int i = p - 1;
    for (int j = p; j < r; j++) {
        int cri = arr[r].maxh;
        if (arr[j].maxh < cri) {
            i++;
            B tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    B tmp = arr[i + 1];
    arr[i + 1] = arr[r];
    arr[r] = tmp;
    return i + 1;
}


void quickSort(B arr[], int p, int r) {

    if (p < r) {
        int q = partition(arr, p, r);
        quickSort(arr, p, q - 1);
        quickSort(arr, q + 1, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use std::sort ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your comparator for `std::sort()`:

See the prototype below:

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

For example you can do:

```
std::sort(
    /*std::begin(b_arr)*/b_arr,
    /*std::end(b_arr)*/b_arr+30000,
    [](const B& left, const B& right){
        return left.maxh < right.maxh;
    }
);
```

Note that `std::begin()` and `std::end()` do not work with pointers to dynamic arrays. In this case you must specify the range by adding the size. I recommend using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Comment: `left.maxh > right.maxh` needs to be `left.maxh < right.maxh` instead. The comparator for `std::sort()` is [*required* to return true only if `left` is **less than** `right` otherwise return false](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). You are doing the opposite.

Comment: thanks. I didn't look closer and intuitively thought he wanted to sort in a reversed order with max at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `std::qsort`, if you define a comparator function for the class objects:

```cpp
int bArrCompare(const void* a, const void* b) {
    const B* pa = reinterpret_cast<const B*>(a);
    const B* pb = reinterpret_cast<const B*>(b);
    return (pb->maxh - pa->maxh);
}

int main()
{
    B* b_arr = new B[30000];
    //...
    std::qsort(b_arr, 30000, sizeof(B), bArrCompare);
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `qsort()` is a C function. Use [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) in  C++.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `std::qsort` is available in `C++` - and it is easier to use for 'old-style pointer' arrays.

Comment: it is not *easier* to use `qsort()` vs `std::sort()`, you can pass an 'old-style pointer' array to `std::sort()` using fewer parameters than `qsort()`, and there is no typecasting needed in the `std::sort()` comparator. So it is actually *easier* to use `std::sort()`, and less error-prone since it has no `size` parameter to get wrong